# Once in hell, under what known circumstances will a person be able to leave?

Tags: hadith, sunni, jannah, hell

Of course, as Muslims we believe that Allah knows what we do not.

However, I was wondering what **known** circusmstances there are under which a person in hell will be able to leave, taking into account the Quran and hadith.

To my knowledge, every Muslim who enters hell will eventually be permitted to leave. Is there anyone else?

Perhaps my memory deceives me, although I think I once read that if a man from paradise desires a woman from hell, then she may leave to be with him? I admit.. it seems like a dodgy memory.

Comment: I will only address last part of your question, hence replying in a comment. Women in Jannah will be so beautiful that if we set our eyes upon them now, we will never desire for anyone else. In Surah Ar Rehman their beauty is briefly mentioned and how pure, chaste and beautiful they are... like the pearls. So IMO, no man in Jannah will ever desire a woman in hell (Non-believer women). So if you have set your eyes upon some actress and they die as disbeliever, there's no chance you will get her even in Akhirah.. Lol. :P

Answer (score 2):

According to my knowledge, all Muslims meaning whoever believes in Allah SWT will eventually enter paradise. The people of paradise will be given special privileges from time to time rescue their beloved ones from the hell. And also Rasulullah(PBUH) (The apostle of Allah) will also continuously ask to Allah SWT to free people from his Ummah from the hellfire.

Answer (score 0):

It is narrated in a Hadith in Sahih Bukhari

> “Then will Allah say, The angels and the prophets and the faithful have all in their turn interceded for the sinners and now there remains none to intercede for them except the Most Merciful of all merciful ones. So He will take out a handful from the Fire and bring out a people who never worked any good.”

Another Hadith in Sahih Muslim it says

> Allah will bring out people from the Fire and admit them into Paradise.

So it is clear that hell is temporary according to the authentic hadiths.

Intercession (shafa'ah) will be done by the Prophet (a.s.); however, from my knowledge, it is **shirk** to ask for intercession